# Which visa consulate I have to apply to get a Schengen Visa

Tags: schengen

This is a very informative guide to get help about Schengen visa enquiries :)

Me and my husband, we are planning for the below itinerary, for a Europe trip covering 5 countries. Please let me know while applying for Schengen visa, which consulate I have to apply from?

Here my longest stay would be in Hungary, but it's not my entry port. So here I am confused !! Please help.

Please Note: I have already booked my hotels and my air tickets.

```
Warsaw,Poland 1 day     
Gdansk,Poland 2 days
Krakow,Poland 3 Days
Prague, Czeck Republic 4 Days
Vienna,Austria 4 Days
Bratislava,Slovakia 1 Day
Budapest,Hungary 7 Days
```